# Error in MVC redirect: Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, https, http-headers

I want to do a simple redirect when a user first loads the website.
For that, I just access the RouteData on `BeginExecuteCore()` method of BaseController and if URL does not have a specific value, then I will redirect to another `https route`:

```
  public class BaseController : Controller
  {
        protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            // access route data

            if (condition == true)
               Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://{0}/en/en", Request.Url.Authority), true);
            }
        }
  }
```

Some facts:

1. I achieve the result I want
2. I get the Exception "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent."
3. I've tried several alternatives: Using other methods to do the redirect like `Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)` etc
4. I tried to Use parameter `EndResponse=true` on Redirect method
5. I tried to clear the headers before doing the redirect
6. In all the previous experiments I got the same exception
7. I'm using `MVC 5`

My question is:
*How can I redirect the user to another route in the most efficient way knowing that I need to have access to RouteData and without throwing the annoying exception?*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Response.Redirect(anyUrl)` cause `302` status code
And `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` has conflict with `302` status code normally.

You can put the following code in `Application_Start`:

```
AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
```

> Security Warning: `SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader =true` prevents your
>   site from being loaded into an iframe.

[read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270192/server-cannot-append-header-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-exception-at-html#34516845)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiair with the method BeginExecuteCore() as i am still working with mvc 3 and 4.

In mvc 4 i would use an action filter to check something before a page loads.

The reason why you are seeing that error is probably because you are to late redirecting the user as the page is already being loaded.

```
 public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
   {
          public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
          {
                if (condition == true)
               filterContext.Response.Redirect(string.Format("https://{0}/en/en", Request.Url.Authority), true);
          }     
     }
```

Take a look at: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't. I got the same exception.
Here's what I did (to be sure I didn't anything that I shouldn't)

1. I adapted your method because there are some change in the way filterContext exposes Request and Response (it worked and I could retrieve the info I needed)

2. Decorated BaseController with with [LogActionFilter]

Comment: 3. Also tried to decorate HomeController instead of BaseController without success..

This code is called after the previous code I have so I think the probability of trying to redirect the user when the page is being loading is higher