# Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent with AntiForgeryToken

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, antiforgerytoken

I'm building my first website using C# and Twitter Bootstrap, and I get the "Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent" error in a Post while finding a validation issue and a `TempData["ErrorMessage"]` needs to be displayed after a `return View(model)`.  The specific error occurs on the html line `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`.  The error does not occur if the message is set and returned to the View outside of the validation.

I've tried: changing the `return View(model)` to a `RedirectToAction ("Action", new { id = model.id })` and `Redirect ("/Controller/Action/" + model.id.ToString())`, which work if the line is outside the validation, but fails when inside the conditional validation;  setting the `AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader` to true inside the `Application_start`; and calling `HttpContext.Response.Clear()` before setting the TempData and returning to the View.  I haven't tried manipulating cookies yet because I'm unsure of how to specifically address the anti-forgery token.

All I want to do is return to the View with the error/validation message displayed on the page instead of as a pop-up message box, and none of the above methods has worked.  Does anyone know why this goal works outside the validation but not inside of it?  Many thanks in advance!

```
//Any return and message works correctly if done here
try
{
    //Various other validations using values pulled from database

    if (model.NewString.Length > 50 || model.NewString.Length < 7)
    {
        //This throws the error
        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Please enter a value of valid length.";
        return View(model);
    }
}
catch
{
    TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "There has been an error.";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**EDIT:** here is the Action as-is per Amit's request.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize (Roles = "Administrator, Owner, Director, Manager")]
[RequireSsl]
public ActionResult CreateCustomer (CreateCustomerModel model)
{
    dbEntities db = new dbEntities();

    var CurrentBusinessID = 0;
    var CurrentPosition = "";
    var CurrentUserID = 0;

    try
    {
        if (Session["CurrentUserID"] != null)
        {
            CurrentUserID = (int)Session["CurrentUserID"];
            CurrentBusinessID = (int)Session["CurrentBusinessInfoID"];
            CurrentPosition = (string)Session["CurrentPosition"];
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("/Account/Logon");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        Response.Redirect("/Account/Logon");
    }

    try
    {
        var account = db.uspGetAccount(model.AccountID).FirstOrDefault();
        AccountsModel thisAccount = new AccountsModel()
        {
            AccountID = model.AccountID,
            BusinessID = account.BusinessID
        };
        if (thisAccount.BusinessID != CurrentBusinessID)
        {
            Response.Redirect("/Home/Dashboard");
        }

        if (model.Name == null || model.Name == "")
        {
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Please enter a name.";
            return View(model);
        }
        if (model.NewString.Length > 50 || model.NewString.Length < 7)
        {
            //This throws the error
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Please enter a value of valid length.";
            return View(model);
        }

        db.AddCustomer(model.Name, model.NewString);
    }
    catch
    {
        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "There has been an error.";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Accounts");
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270192/server-cannot-append-header-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-exception-at-html

Comment: @Amit - thank you for the link, but I actually implemented the answer and it didn't work.  Specifically, when I mention the change to RedirectToAction and Redirect plus the SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader in my answer, that was the post I was following.

Comment: Can you paste your controller code for this method as is. If your if statement for Model.NewString does not work, there is no return statement. Also, you can try Response.ClearHeaders() before any return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by changing the `Reponse.Redirect("/Home/Dashboard")` inside the `if` statement within the `try` statement containing the validation.  Changing this line to return `RedirectToAction("Accounts")` solved the problem, although I'm not sure why.

```
if (thisAccount.BusinessID != CurrentBusinessID)
{
    Response.Redirect("/Home/Dashboard");//Solve the problem by replacing this
}
```

Comment: Check with your debugger, line by line.                                               https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/03/01/response-redirect-and-asp-net-mvc-do-not-mix/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159523/why-do-i-get-cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-when-i-call-res